# Setting tag in Tkinter text - tag's range starts with 1.1 all the time despite further changes

Tags: python, tkinter

In my Tkinter GUI I try to create a functionality in which a user rewrites the given text in entry widget, word after word. The colours of the text should change according to the fact if words were written correctly or not. The problem is that ranges of tags I've created always start with 1.1 even though I set the beginnings as position of the first letter in each word.   "
For example the second word in the text starts on position 10 in the string, after I use space key twice: `text.tag_ranges(tag_name)` returns `(<string object: '1.1'>, <string object: '1.15'>)`,
but when I `print(start)` it gives me what I expect: `1.10`". The result is that the colouring always starts at the beginnig of the text, not of the word. The end is always ok. Is there something wrong I can't see?

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

t = "quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi"
text_split = t.split()
last_char = len(t)
whitespaces_list = [0] + [i.start() for i in re.finditer(" ", t)] + [last_char]

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('750x600')

n = 0


def next_word(event):
    global n
    n = n + 1
    z = text_split[n - 1]
    correct_word = re.search(z, entry.get())

    if n < len(whitespaces_list):
        start = '1.' + str(whitespaces_list[n - 1])
        end = '1.' + str(whitespaces_list[n])
        for x in range(len(text_split) - 1):
            text.tag_add(str(x), start, end)
        # print(text.tag_ranges(str(x)))
        # print(start)
        # print(end)
        if correct_word:
            text.tag_config(str(x), foreground="green")
        else:
            text.tag_config(str(x), foreground="red")

    entry.delete(0, tk.END)


label1 = tk.Label(width=200, height=10)
label1.pack()

text = tk.Text(label1)
text.place(x=40, y=20)
text.insert(tk.INSERT, t)

label2 = tk.Label(height=80, width=200)
label2.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(label2)
entry.place(x=300, y=20)

window.bind("<space>", next_word)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: first of I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from tkinter import Tk, Text, Entry` and so on or import the whole module: `import tkinter` then You can also use an alias: `import tkinter as tk` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing because today I came across an issue that was caused because of wildcard imports; name clashes are the issue. about the problem tho, it would be great if You showed what `text` and `entry` represent, show a [mre]

Comment: I added the shortest possible full version of code causing the problem, with your tip about import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution that turned out to be very simple, I incorrectly set the loop, it should be removed and the correct part of code is:

```
if n < len(whitespaces_list):
    start = '1.' + str(whitespaces_list[n - 1])
    end = '1.' + str(whitespaces_list[n])
text.tag_add(str(n), start, end)
if correct_word:
    text.tag_config(str(n), foreground="green")
else:
    text.tag_config(str(n), foreground="red")
```

Thank you Derek and Matiiss for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates how to use `Text` search, `tag_config` and `tag_add`

I've included a filedialog text loader via `Control-L`

The `Entry` object is used to search for word or phrase. If found they are all highlighted and results are stored in dictionary findstore by name(str) and place(list).

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido

def flexx( o, r = 0, c = 0, rs = 1, cs = 1 ):
    if r != None:
        o.rowconfigure( r, weight = rs )
    if c != None:
        o.columnconfigure( c, weight = cs )

findstore = dict( name = '', place = [] )

window = tk.Tk()
flexx( window )

label = tk.LabelFrame( window, labelanchor = tk.N, text = "Banner" )
label.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW )
flexx( label )

text = tk.Text(
    label, undo = 1, takefocus = 1,
    font = "Consolas 10 normal", wrap = tk.NONE )
text.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW )

scroll = tk.Scrollbar( window, orient = tk.VERTICAL, command = text.yview )
scroll.grid( row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NS )
text[ 'yscrollcommand' ] = scroll.set

entry = tk.Entry(
    window, width = 20, takefocus = 1, font = "Consolas 20 normal" )
entry.grid( row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.EW )

window.update_idletasks( )

t = "quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi\n" + "\n\n".join( dir( text ) )

text.insert( tk.INSERT, t )


def closer( ev ):
    window.destroy( )

def banner( n ):
    label[ "text" ] = f"{n}"

def find( k, color = "#00eeee" ):
    """search from the beginning"""
    global i
    p = "1.0"
    i = [ ]
    ln = len( k )
    if len( k ) > 0:
        # use text search
        while 1:
            p = text.search( k, p, stopindex="end" )
            if p == "":
                break
            i.append( p )
            p += "+1c"
        if i:
            p = i[ 0 ]
            if "" in i:
                i.remove( "" )
            banner( f"Found( {len(i)} )" )
            # use color as tagname
            if len( i ) > 0:
                text.tag_delete( color )
                text.tag_config( color, foreground = color, font = "Consolas 12 bold" )
                findstore.update( name = k, place = i )
                for a in i:
                    text.tag_add( color, a, f"{a}+{ln}c" )

def next_word( ev ):
    word = entry.get( )
    entry.delete( 0, tk.END )
    # search for word|phrase
    find( word )
    # Store results in findstore
    print( findstore[ 'name' ], findstore[ 'place' ] )

def loadfile( ev ):
    pathfilename = fido.askopenfilename( title = "Choose a text file" )
    if os.path.exists( pathfilename ):
        with open( pathfilename, mode = 'rt' ) as loader:
            info = loader.read()
        text.delete( '1.0', 'end' )
        text.insert( '1.0', info )
        text.edit_reset( )
        banner( os.path.split( pathfilename )[ 1 ] )

entry.bind( "<Return>", next_word )
window.bind( "<Escape>", closer )
window.bind( "<Control-L>", loadfile )

entry.focus_set()
window.mainloop()
```